# how to do data sharing of service among two different components in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am in learning mode of Angular 2 . I am implementing the singleton service in angular just to know how does it work.
this is my service class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor() {
        console.log("new instance");
    }
    dataValue: string = "i am singleton";
}
```

Here it is my Two components where i am using this service first one

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './dataservice';

@Component({
    selector: 'first',
    template: `
                 <div>
                        Your Input : <input type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "ChangeByFirstComponent">
                        You Entered : {{ChangeByFirstComponent}}
                 </div>   
                `
})

export class FirstComponent {
    constructor(private _dataService: DataService) { }
    ChangeByFirstComponent: string;

    get DataValue(): string {
        return this._dataService.dataValue;
    }

    set DataValue(ChangeByFirstComponent)
        {
            this._dataService.dataValue = this.ChangeByFirstComponent;
        }
}
second one 
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './dataservice';

@Component({
    selector: 'second',
    template: `
                 <div>
                        Your Input : <input type = "text" [(ngModel)] = "ChangeBySecondComponent">
                        You Entered : {{ChangeBySecondComponent}}
                 </div>  ` 

})

export class SecondComponent {
    constructor(private _dataService: DataService) { }
    ChangeBySecondComponent: string;

    get DataValue(): string {
        return this._dataService.dataValue;
    }

    set DataValue(ChangeByFirstComponent) {
        this._dataService.dataValue = this.ChangeBySecondComponent;
    }
}
```

I provided the providers in root module for single instance hence and it is working fine as i checked it throw developer tool.
I am implementing that if the user change the value from firstcomponent so it should change on secondcomponent to (this is what singleton provided us , makes data sharing easily) . I am not getting my output . what is the problem ?

Comment: Use a `BehaviorSubject` in the service to share data, then the code in components doesn't depend on a specific execution order (read before value is set)

Comment: i am not getting you sorry

Comment: If `SecondComponent` reads the data before `FristComponent` writes one, you won't get a value. With a `BehaviorSubject` `SecondComponent` can subscribe and gets notified when `FirstComponent` passes a value. There should be enough examples here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BehaviorSubject` to accomplish this, more on `BehaviorSubject` [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md)
I already gave answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506012/how-to-update-data-in-2-components-using-single-instance-of-the-service-class-in)